# Finding lines where a table is inserted and updated with dba_source

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to find all insert, update , and merge lines in whole dba

what i tried:

```
SELECT owner, name, type,line,text
FROM dba_source where regexp_like(text,'into my_table')
union all
SELECT owner, name, type,line,text
FROM dba_source where regexp_like(text,'update my_table')
```

but nothing returns from my select function.

EDIT:  The return must contain specific table. Return should not contain tables like "my_table_2" or "my_table_temp"

Comment: Are you on right Db or Master ?

Comment: Change to using uppercase or use the `'i'` flag in `REGEXP_LIKE`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I mentioned in comments, one issue could be the case of the text. Another could be the number of white-space characters between the characters.

```
SELECT owner,
       name,
       type,
       line,
       text
FROM   dba_source
WHERE  REGEXP_LIKE(
         text,
         '(into|update)\s+table_name(\s|$)',
             -- Match both conditions and any amount of white-space
         'i' -- Case insensitive
       )
```

You then need to deal with other case where:

- The table identifier is on the next line from the `INTO` or `UPDATE` keyword;
- The table identifier has a schema prefix `SCHEMA_NAME.TABLE_NAME`; or
- The an identifier is quoted `"TABLE_NAME"` or `"SCHEMA_NAME"."TABLE_NAME"`;
- A combination of the above.

Which would give you an expression like:

```
SELECT owner,
       name,
       type,
       line,
       text
FROM   dba_source
WHERE  REGEXP_LIKE(
         text,
         '(into|update)\s+(("?)schema_name\3\.)?("?)table_name\4(\s|$)',
             -- Match both conditions, schema, quotes and any amount of white-space
         'i' -- Case insensitive
       )
```

You could also use `LAG` or `LEAD` to look for statements spread across lines.

Comment: how can i cut returns from other tables which contains my table's name in string. I only want a specific table like "my_table" there so many tables in return. Btw thanks you for that answer and information

Comment: @ArdaNalbant My previous edit added that - the `(\s|$)` at the end of the regular expression will enforce that the identifier ends.

Comment: Exactly what i need ty

Answer (score 3):

You are not using a very good method to search. You will not get any results, if the source is saved in the below way -

```
insert
  into
 any_table
```

Because there are multiple new lines, so your query from dba_source/all_source will fail.

A better way to find that is -

```
select * from dba_dependencies
 where referenced_name = 'TABLE_NAME|SYNONYM_NAME'
   and referenced_type = 'TABLE|SYNONYM'
```

Example,

suppose you have a `PROCEDURE XYZ`, which has the below construct

```
create or replace procedure xyz
begin    
    insert 
      into 
    any_table ....
end;
```

Then, if you run the below query

```
select * from dba_dependencies
 where referenced_name = 'any_table'
   and referenced_type = 'TABLE';
```

The result of the above query will give you 'XYZ' as a record.

Comment: can you explain with example please. Thanks for replying. Also how can i manage my table name. consider that there so many tables starts with my_table...blabla

Comment: @ArdaNalbant - Added example

Comment: Very good aproach. It fails for dynamic SQL, but well, it is close to impossible to write a fail-safe query for this.

Answer (score 1):

There are several things to consider:

1. there may be space between the keyword INSERT and the table name
2. there may be a schema name preceding the table name (my_schema.my_table)
3. the table name may be in upper or lower case or a mix of them
4. excluding my_table_xxx for a search on my_table, as you already mentioned

Here is a query for this:

```
SELECT owner, name, type, line, text
FROM dba_source 
WHERE regexp_like(text, '(update|into)[[:space:]]+my_table($|\s|\W)', 'i')
   OR regexp_like(text, '(update|into)[[:space:]]+[[:alpha:]]+\.my_table($|\s|\W)', 'i');
```

However, this still doesn't cover the case where you have INSERT in one line and the table name in the next.

Comment: Oh, I see I'm a little late. MT0 has given you about the same answer some minutes before mine.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:-

```
SELECT owner, name, type,line,text
FROM dba_source where regexp_like(UPPER(text),'INTO YOUR_TABLE_NAME')
union all
SELECT owner, name, type,line,text
FROM dba_source where regexp_like(UPPER(text),'UPDATE YOUR_TABLE_NAME');
```